# makefile - define dependency using variable with objects when building many executables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm following great tutorial about ffmpeg (http://dranger.com/ffmpeg) and I'm trying to build a generic makefile for it.

My problem is that I cannot define a generic rule for executables to be depenent on an object of the same name but with ".o" suffix.

Example: when invoked `make all` I want to build 2 executables `tutorial01` and `tutorial02` out of 2 files `tutorial01.cpp` and `tutorial02.cpp`, but first I want to compile them into `*.o` and then link them.

My whole Makefile is like so:

```
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
CXXFLAGS+=`sdl-config --cflags`

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LDFLAGS+=-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LDFLAGS+=-lavutil-ffmpeg -lavcodec-ffmpeg -lavformat-ffmpeg -lswscale-ffmpeg
LDFLAGS+=`sdl-config --libs`

SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLES=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)
all : $(EXECUTABLES)

# Not working:
#%$(EXECUTABLES) : $(OBJECTS)
#   $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)
#
# Not working (always substitutes the first found):
#$(EXECUTABLES) : $(OBJECTS)
#   $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)
#
# Not working:
#for exec in $(EXECUTABLES) ; do \
#$(exec) : $(exec).o ; \
#done
#
# Working:
#tutorial01:tutorial01.o
#tutorial02:tutorial02.o
#tutorial03:tutorial03.o

%: %.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLES)
```

I tried what is stated above as "not working" and also gave an example of what is working but not generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Not working (always substitutes the first found):
$(EXECUTABLES) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)
```

This fails because `$(OBJECTS)` expands to something like `tutorial01.o tutorial02.o tutorial03.o` for all targets, and `$<` expands to the *first* prerequisite, which is the same (`tutorial01.o`) for all targets.

```
# Not working:
for exec in $(EXECUTABLES) ; do \
$(exec) : $(exec).o ; \
done
```

This fails because it is for-loop written in shell syntax. You can write a for-loop in Make syntax, but it is not needed here.

I would use a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
tutorial%: tutorial%.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)
```

or a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(EXECUTABLES): %: %.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_LIBS)
```

Comment: Static pattern rule was exactly what I was looking for, because it works with any "EXECUTABLE" name that matches cpp file. Thank you.